# Interchangeability of limits when n → ∞ and n → 0⁺

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

How does one prove that if f(n) → ξ ∈ ℝ when n → ∞ then f(1/n) → ξ  when n → 0⁺?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, using my mantra "What would Walter Rudin do?"...

He would, in Princliples of mathematical anlysis, declare Theorem 4.2

$\lim_{x\rightarrow p} f(x) = q$ iff $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(p_n) = q$ for every sequence $\{p_n\}$ such that $p_n \ne p$ and $p_n \rightarrow p$

And the proof is done by delta-epsilon definitions.  There are no surprises.

So yours:

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(n) = q$ means

$\forall \epsilon > 0$ there is a $N$ so that whenever $n > N$ we have $d(f(n),q) < \epsilon$

Let $\delta$ be so that $0 < \delta < 1/N$.  So if $0 < m < \delta$ then $1/m > N$ and $d(f(1/m), q) < \epsilon$

which means

$\lim_{n\rightarrow 0^+} f(1/n) = q$.